# Dynamically add buttons in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am writing an iOS app. Server gives me buttons array to draw on view. So, the number of buttons can vary according to server response,
example:

```
let buttonArray=["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"]
or
let buttonArray=["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"," Button 4", "Button 5"]
```

I have to **stack these buttons vertically**.
I created a **stackview**, add **constraints** to it, and then **add** buttons to this stackview as **arrangedsubviews**. 
Buttons should have **gap of 5 points** between them:

**Using stackview:**

```
func addButtonsUsingStackView()
    {
        //create stackview:
        let stackView=UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        //stackview constraints:
        let viewsDictionary = ["stackView":stackView]
        let stackView_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[stackView]-20-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: viewsDictionary)
        let stackView_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|-30-[stackView]-30-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: viewsDictionary)
        view.addConstraints(stackView_H)
        view.addConstraints(stackView_V)

        //adding buttons to stackview:

        //let buttonArray=["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"]
        let buttonArray=["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"," Button 4"]

        for buttonName in buttonArray{

            let button=UIButton()
            button.setTitle(buttonName, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor=UIColor.blue
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)

        }

    }
```

**Without stackview:**

```
var buttonArray=["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"," Button 4"," Button 5"," Button 6"," Button 7"]

    func addButtonsLoop()
    {

        for _view in view.subviews{
            _view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        var i=0
        var buttonY = 20
        let buttonGap=5

        for btn in buttonArray {

            let buttonHeight=Int(Int(view.frame.height) - 40 - (buttonArray.count * buttonGap))/buttonArray.count
            print(buttonHeight)
            let buttonWidth=Int(view.frame.width - 40)

            let button = UIButton()
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            button.setTitle(btn, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: buttonY, width:buttonWidth , height:buttonHeight)
            button.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
            buttonY += buttonHeight + buttonGap
            button.tag = i
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(button)

            i+=1

        }
    }

    func buttonTapped( _ button : UIButton)
    {
        buttonArray.remove(at: button.tag)
        addButtonsLoop()
    }
```

My question is that instead of above code, how to apply **NSLayoutConstraints** or **LayoutAnchors** to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stack view you can use a tableview with the tableview cell containing a button and the number of rows can be the buttonarray count. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method set the button title from button array.

Comment: Can you please tell me without using tableView and stackview?

Comment: If you don't want to use either stackview of tableview then you have to calculate the frame of each button and add those button to the view.

Comment: if on tap of button, it gets removed from view, how shall I maintain constraints?

Comment: If you don't want to show the button again, then on the IBAction you can remove that tapped button from ButtonArray and call the function that you have written to place the buttons. Sorry, here I strongly recommend you to use tableview/stackview because it is easy to do these type of addition and removal and on using tableview you can manage scrolling effectively if ample number of buttons are there.

Comment: Thank you, tableView is recommended, but my question is without using any of controls.  
Without using any of these, I want to add dynamically buttons to view with 5 points gap between them and on tapping button it removes from view but, constraints should not fail.!

Comment: If you don't want to show the button again, then on the IBAction you can remove that tapped button from ButtonArray and call the function that you have written to place the buttons. Sorry, here I strongly recommend you to use tableview/stackview because it is easy to do these type of addition and removal and on using tableview you can manage scrolling effectively if ample number of buttons are there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use scroll view to add buttons.

```
var btnY = 5
let btnHeight = 40
func addButtonsUsingStackView()
        {
    for view in self.view.subviews{
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            for i in 0..< buttonArray.count {

                let btnFloor = UIButton()
                btnFloor.backgroundColor = Orange       
                btnFloor.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
                btnFloor.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: btnY, width: Int(scrView.frame.width - 20), height: btnHeight)
                btnFloor.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
                btnY += btnHeight + 5
                btnFloor.tag = buttonArray.index(of: i)
                btnFloor.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTappedFloor(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                self.view.addSubview(btnFloor)
            }
            return cell
        }

 func btnTappedFloor( _ button : UIButton)
 {
      buttonArray.remove(at: button.tag)
      addButtonsUsingStackView()
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me without using tableView or scrollView or  stackview?

Comment: Without using any of these, I want to add dynamically buttons to view with 5 points gap between them and on tapping button it removes from view but, constraints should not fail.!

Comment: btnFloorHeight?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified my question according to your answer. Now, is there any more optimised way to solve this? Instead of above code, how could I use NSLayoutConstraints or LayoutAnchors because above code doesn't support rotating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146057/discussion-between-atif-shabeer-and-nishant-bhindi).